# Is it possible to give and Android App a configurable name?

Tags: android, android-manifest

Basically can the name of the app itself that is displayed when you are browsing apps, be changed to be a number of different values, without requiring a different apk for each name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's possible, you can [have a look over here.](https://blog.jakelee.co.uk/programmatically-changing-app-icon/)

You can change app icon n app label programmatically within the app.